# Execute in Where clause if variable is not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write stored procedure that will execute code if variable is not null

```
 @PageNumber INT = 1
,@PageSize INT = 100
,@Latitude DECIMAL(9, 6) NULL
,@Longitude DECIMAL(9, 6) NULL
,@Radius INT NULL

SELECT lst.[Id]
    ,lst.[Number]
FROM dbo.[Listing] lst
INNER JOIN dbo.[Branch] bra ON bra.[Id] = lst.BranchStartId
WHERE 
    *Pseudo Code*
    IF (@Latitude > 0 AND @Longitude > 0 AND @Radius > 0)
    BEGIN
    (acos(sin(bra.Latitude * 0.0175) * sin(@Latitude * 0.0175) + cos(bra.Latitude * 0.0175) * cos(@Latitude * 0.0175) * cos((@Longitude * 0.0175) - (bra.Longitude * 0.0175))) * 6371 <= @Radius)
    END
    ELSE
      *select all*
    END

ORDER BY Id DESC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Can it be done without writing dynamic query?

I have figured out that it can be done by:

```
IF (@Latitude > 0 AND @Longitude > 0 AND @Radius > 0)
BEGIN
SELECT lst.[Id]
    ,lst.[Number]
FROM dbo.[Listing] lst
INNER JOIN dbo.[Branch] bra ON bra.[Id] = lst.BranchStartId
WHERE (acos(sin(bra.Latitude * 0.0175) * sin(@Latitude * 0.0175) + cos(bra.Latitude * 0.0175) * cos(@Latitude * 0.0175) * cos((@Longitude * 0.0175) - (bra.Longitude * 0.0175))) * 6371 <= @Radius)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT lst.[Id]
    ,lst.[Number]
FROM dbo.[Listing] lst
INNER JOIN dbo.[Branch] bra ON bra.[Id] = lst.BranchStartId
END
```

But in this scenario I am not able to get auto generated return type with linq to sql. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want simple logical comparisons with `OR`:

```
WHERE @Latitude IS NULL OR @Longitude IS NULL OR @Radius IS NULL OR
    (acos(sin(bra.Latitude * 0.0175) * sin(@Latitude * 0.0175) + cos(bra.Latitude * 0.0175) * cos(@Latitude * 0.0175) * cos((@Longitude * 0.0175) - (bra.Longitude * 0.0175))) * 6371 <= @Radius)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!